# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) React Native AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am promisifying the React Native AsyncStorage `getItem` method but I am being warned that it is returning a possible unhandled promise rejection. Here's what I'm doing, what's wrong with my code?

In App.js `ComponentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  ConnectyCube.init(...config);
  authInitialization = async () => {
    const locallyStoredPhoneNumber = await getStoredPhoneNumber();
    console.log(locallyStoredPhoneNumber);
    authorizeFirebase(this.getFirebaseAccessToken);
    this.props.authorizing(true);
  }
  authInitialization();
}
```

Then in `localStorage.js`

```
export const getStoredPhoneNumber = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@phone_number', (error, result) => {
      result ? resolve(result) : reject(error);
    })
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

#### UPDATE

I have now added error handling:

```
export const getStoredPhoneNumber = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@phone_number', (error, result) => {
      result ? resolve(result) : reject(error);
    })
  }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Seems to work - here's my extra logic that depends on the result of the `AsyncStorage` call:

```
componentDidMount() {
  ConnectyCube.init(...config);
  authInitialization = async () => {
    const locallyStoredPhoneNumber = await getStoredPhoneNumber();
    locallyStoredPhoneNumber !== undefined
      ? authorizeFirebase(this.getFirebaseAccessToken) && this.props.authorizing(true)
      : this.setState({ newUser: true })
  }
  authInitialization();
}
```

Comment: i mean... nowhere in that code are you handling rejected promises. If a promise is rejected, and you're not handling it, it's "unhandled"

Comment: Thanks @KevinB - I see that now - what I'm trying to do as you can see from the async function inside `componentDidMount` is wait for the `AsyncStorage` call to be resolved and then move on through the rest of the function.

Comment: And? you're still not handling any errors that might occur. It doesn't matter what you are trying to do, you have promises without error handling. That's all the error is telling you.

Comment: So the reason I don't have a `try catch` block in the code is because I am attempting to promisify the result of the `AsyncStorage` call so I can make `ComponentDidMount` `async`. Maybe my question should have been how can I achieve what I just described.

Comment: I was following the `Signature` in the [Documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/API.md). `getItem(key: string, [callback]: ?(error: ?Error, result: ?string) => void): Promise`

Comment: examples and documentation often leave out the error handling to make the code look cleaner.

Comment: However... that link you provided in a comment above, has a very good example of proper error handling with AsyncStorage methods.

Comment: Yes - but with `try catch` I can't await the success or failure of the `AsyncStorage` call in an asynchronous function inside my container component. I want `componentDidiMount` to wait for its success or failure.

Comment: no matter what you do, componentDidMount isn't going to wait if it isn't async. No amount of async/await or promise wrapping will change that. I don't quite understand why you need componentDidMount to wait. You don't have any additional logic for it to run on success/failure... so what is it waiting to do?

Comment: @KevinB have added the extra logic above.

Comment: why are you promisifying asyncstorage.getItem?  It already returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM - I wanted to make the other methods wait for success / failure of funding the item in local storage.

Comment: @tommmmmmmy `AsyncStorage.getItem` already returns a promise, so you can  `await` the results without having to create another promise (as shown in my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this should work:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  ConnectyCube.init(...config);
  try {
    const locallyStoredPhoneNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@phone_number');
    locallyStoredPhoneNumber !== undefined
      ? authorizeFirebase(this.getFirebaseAccessToken) && this.props.authorizing(true)
      : this.setState({ newUser: true })
  } catch (e){
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike M - within `authorizeFirbase` and `getFirebaseAccessToken` there are up to five asynchronous api calls and any one of them could fail - they already have their own catch methods. Doesn't your solution above reduce the the ability to handle these failed calls?

Comment: Also, how come we can use `await` without making it an `async` function?

Comment: @tommmmmmmy the try/catch should catch any errors being thrown from firebase.  We can use `await` because I made `componentDidMount` an async.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'catch' any errors which might be thrown and handle them (otherwise React will complain):

```
componentDidMount() {
  authInitialization = async () => {
    try {
      const locallyStoredPhoneNumber = await getStoredPhoneNumber();
    ...
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e) //handle error }
    }
    authInitialization();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle promise rejection would be to use `try...catch` block where your promise is being returned.

```
try{
    const locallyStoredPhoneNumber = await getStoredPhoneNumber();
} catch(error){
    //Error handling code here
}
```